# Is there an online example sentence database or search engine to translate LIST of words?

Tags: discussion, resources

I need to find sentence examples for list of words that includes in about 1500 words.So it is not easy to use online services that find examples only for one word(like Google translate or some other that are described [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/is-there-an-online-sample-sentence-database-or-search-engine)) and do copy/paste founded examples.Exactly I want to find a web page like [EasyDefine](http://www.easydefine.com/).I can copy and paste all of words of my list in it and it get definition for them.But unfortunately it gets "definition" and I need to examples.Do you know any solution?

Comment: Is your list of words ~1500 long? Google API?

Comment: @Mitch ,if I copy my list into Google translate,it only translate words and does not show examples.Also I tried to write a computer program that used Google API,but it is not free.So I can not use it.

Comment: You'll still have to do words one at a time, no matter how you do it, unless you build your own database and/or parsing software to extract individual sentences from text. If you have a list of individual sentences (say, the 2.5 million example sentences in the OED), you could use fgrep or some similar tool to do parallel searches. Or you could look them up in the OED individually and get lists for each word; there are usually between 2000 and 10,000 example sentences in the OED for any common English word.